# Why does it take so long to start a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, time

Given the following (which I have taken from a larger program)

```
t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int j = i; j <= 1000; j += 3) {
        t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //j loop body
    }  
}
```

When I run the program and test it for speed, I find that

t2 - t1 is around 2700 milliseconds

t3 - t2 is around 1300 milliseconds

In comparison, the following program prints a time of 3 milliseconds to the console

```
public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int k = 0; k < 1000000; k++) {
            sum += k;
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

How can simply entering the i and j for loops take so much time?

I appreciate that I haven't shown the full program for the i and j loops, but if anyone knows of any reason why this might be happening, that would save me creating an appropriate sample program (that isn't too big) to post here.

Comment: Where are you checking `t3 - t2`? Unless it’s inside the first iteration of the inner loop, you’re going to be measuring the entire running time of the loop.

Comment: Worth reading if you haven't done so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Thanks. I see why now, because I was doing the time comparisons outside of the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set `t1` only once, `t2` 3 times, and `t3` around 1000 times.

you compare `t1` with the last time you set `t2`.
you compare the last time you set `t2` with the last time you set `t3`.

the first comparison shows you the combined runtime of the inner loops first 2 iterations.
the second comparison shows you the runtime of the inner loops 3rd (==last) iteration.

thus your numbers make perfect sense, as the first comparison is about 2 times as large as the second one.

Answer (score -1):

System.currentTimeMillis(); takes a long itme **the faster code does not call a function within its for loop**

any type of function calling is more work for the cpu than a simple statement or arithmetic operation